# .Net project always rebuilds, not up to date caused by CopyLocal property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

No matter what I do my .net Project will always rebuild. I read this Article https://oz-code.com/blog/visual-studio-keeps-rebuilding-projects-no-good-reason/, and I found the CopyLocal problem in my Project.

I got this message: `Project 'PROJECTNAME' is not up to date. CopyLocal reference 'D:\...PROJECTPATH...\bin\x64\Debug\System.Net.Http.dll' is missing from output location.`.

My System.Net.Http.dll is referenced like this (Don't ask me why Private is set twice): [image: .csproj reference]

Visual Studio itself shows me it is taken from the "Reference Assemblies": 
[image]

And as I figured out, Assemblies taken from the "Reference Assemblies" are never copied to the output folder.

Now the problem, if I change the CopyLocal to false it works, but after any NuGet restore it will be set to True again. I assume this is caused by the fact that the HintPath is refereing to a NuGet package where CopyLocal should be set to True.

It only happens with "System.*" references. The Project is .net 4.8 and I'm using the latest VS2019.

Is there any way to prevent this, or did i miss something how I can fix this? This is happening in a quite big solution and it takes forever to build if everything is rebuilt all the time.

I tried ReSharper-Build, and that worked but if possible i would like to stick to the standard.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have *two* references to System.Net.Http.dll.  One came from a nuget package, the other is the normal framework reference.  You only need one, ditch the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to prevent this, or did i miss something how I can
>   fix this? This is happening in a quite big solution and it takes
>   forever to build if everything is rebuilt all the time.

As **Hans** said, you reference two `system.net.http.dll` in the same project in different ways so that it creates a build mess, making it impossible to determine the version of the reference. And it turns always rebuild.

In fact, `System.Net.Http.dll` is just a part of `Net Framework4.8` and exists in the [Reference assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies).

All of this points to the fact that this is a public,global DLL that can be used directly in VS without having to install it using nuget. So I'm curious why you're still using nuget to install it.

**Note**: When you create a new `net frameowrk4.8` project and then open reference, and you will find that it already references `system.net.http.dll` from Reference assemblies. So when you use nuget to install it or use the path of the nuget in the `HintPath`, it will not change the inital path.

**Solution**

To solve it, please uninstall the nuget package `System.Net.Http`.Right-click on the project-->`Manage Nuget Packages`--> uninstall it.

[image]

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw that https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/ references the System.Net.Http NuGet package, for the .NET Framework 4.5, somehow this dependency is also triggered for .NET 4.8. I tested it with a clean project on .NET Framework 4.8, nothing added. I just added the ActiveDirectory NuGet, it keeps rebuilding all the time, unless i force uninstall all System.* NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

I comment on the original question and the answer provided already provide the why this is happening

> You have system dlls explicitly included in your project

and the solution to fix this is to

> remove the reference to a specific version of the system Dll or remove the reference all together

I found myself in this situation. I really don't have any insight into how this happened to my project that has evolved over 7 years. But I did want to share how to find out if you are in this situation beside the repeated rebuilds for no reason.

The key was in the OP's comment about `<Private>True</Private>`. If you search for that in your .csproj files and find it, then you likely have some clean up to do. This is also a very efficient way to clean things up - by doing a search rather than trying to rebuild repeatedly until no rebuild happens. (This assumes you have many projects in your solution).

My approach has been to do a search across all files for `<Private>True</Private>` and then for each project file that contains that string, unload the project and remove the reference, then reload the project.

If you have an error after reloading your project, then you need to add back the reference that you removed. But you need to do it in a version agnostic manner.

For instance, I found lines like this in my csproj files:

```
    <Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

This would need to be replaced with

```
    <Reference Include="System.IO" />
```

Once you have removed all of the references with `<Private>True<Private>`, you should be good to go.

Note: I am sure there is a valid reason for the Private=True, I am unaware of what that is, but if you need it, then I suspect you are also aware of what the real use is and wont blindly remove it.